# Should I filter data in backend or frontend?

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot, redux

I have a web service built with Spring, my view is built with React and I use Redux for state management.

Let's say my API has an endpoint `/api/products` and I've implemenented search functionality, which pulls all the products from the enpoint, stores them in Redux store and displays them. Now I want to implement sorting functionality and I have two ideas for achieving it:

1. Modify my api endpoint `/api/products` to take parameters. For example `/api/products?sortBy=price` (less logic in  UI, more network requests)
2. Use the products that I have stored in the store. (less network requests, more logic in UI)

Which one of these, if any, would be considered as the best practice?

Answer (score 6):

It would depend on

- What is the acceptable latency? How often do you need to call this list? Almost every second, like in an autocomplete field? Say, a few times a minute, for a report which is sorted by different parameters by the user? Or something like a rarely used settings page?
- How much data do you have? Is it a few million? or a few dozen? If it is too many, better to filter in the backend and send only the required rows.
- How big is each row? If each row is big with many fields, your payload will increase.
- Are you having to make a tradeoff between initial load time (to load all the data from the backend once) vs responsiveness (when the user is interacting with the data)?

I hope this will give you the general idea on how to decide. Maybe able to discuss more if you have details of your specific situation.

Comment: Helpful, but it would be nice to have some kind of measurement on how much (product data) for example one could still filter on the frontend. (I realize that depends on the specific data itself.) But I guess we should just pick one, and test the filter speed to see if it suits our needs. Or any more specific advice?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backend. If you have like 3000 records, you need to use pagination. You shouldn't sort all pages on frontend, because it would be too much data. You need to use backend to sort and send only data you want to display on specific page.

Answer (score -1):

Please dont use backend functionality in your Frontend.
Spring Boot is an great framework and offers you Sort and Pageing functionalities.

Example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

  Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
  List<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Sort sort);
}
```

Please look into the Documentation -> [Spring Data Jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Comment: OP should switch to spring boot ?